# Rails 4 Inherited Resources throwing ConstraintException when posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

I have a pretty simple model called Deal with name and description where name is non-nullable.

When I post the following to /api/deals

```
{"name":"oaeu"}
```

I get the error

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: deals.name may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "deals" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)

My Model

```
enter code here
```

My Controller

```
class DealsController < InheritedResources::Base

   protected
   def permitted_params
     params.require(:deal).permit(:name)
   end
end
```

My Model

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I can't figure out what is going on!!!

My Gemfile includes:

> gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

and

> gem 'inherited_resources'

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you actually saving the Deal object?

Comment: inherited resource handle the saving.  I don't need to do anything to make it work.  I have already done that with an older project on rails 3.x and ruby 1.9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Params**

Firstly, your `strong params` are incorrect:

```
  def permitted_params
     params.permit(deal: [:name])
  end
```

As mentioned in [this blog post](http://abernardes.github.io/2013/08/21/inherited-resources-with-strong-parameters.html), and this [github post](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#strong-parameters), you'll get errors unless use the above code!

---

**Saving**

As mentioned in the comments, it seems your save process is by-passing your inherited resources controller

It seems you're using an API, so perhaps that it sending straight to the model; either way, you'll have to detail how you're saving the inbound data

Comment: I will try the params.permit syntax you suggested but the saving part, I don't think I understand what you mean.  The inherited resource controller should handle all the saving automatically.  I use the controller to retrieve deals with no problems.

Comment: Your answer is partly right but I will give it to you.  The correct syntax is:  params.permit(:deal => [:name])

edit your answer if you can :) - thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to overwrite the #resource_params method in your controller.

```
def resource_params
    [ params.require(:deal).permit(:name) ]
end
```

See:
https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/236
http://blog.josemarluedke.com/posts/inherited-resources-with-rails-4-and-strong-parameters